# Gold Parser Lowercase

Tags: parsing, uppercase, lowercase, gold-parser

### Gold Parser issue: Having a problem with Uppercase/Lowercase character differentiation. The following in my grammar is failing:

LowercaseLetter = {&61 .. &7A}

LowercaseLetters = LowercaseLetter+

UppercaseLetter = {&41 .. &5A}

UppercaseLetters = UppercaseLetter+

---

I get a 'DFA State' indicating 'Cannot distinguish between LowercaseLetter and UppercaseLetter'.

I find this confusing because I believe that LowercaseLetter is defined by the set of ascii characters 'a' through to 'z', and UppercaseLetter is defined by the set of ascii characters 'A' through to 'Z'.

Any assistance most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to set the Parameter, "Case Sensitive", to True within your Grammar, as follows:

"Case Sensitive" = 'True'